# bootstrap datepicker, beforeShowDay works after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have some issues with `beforeShowDay` function with bootstrap datepicker. My intention is when I click any day, the 5 days after the selected day must contain the active class.

When the page loads, the function works perfectly. But when I try to choose any other day, I must double click if I want the function to work. The function must work with 1 click. Is something wrong?

```
var selectedDay = new Date().getTime();
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var d = date.getTime();
        if (d > selectedDay && d < selectedDay + 1 + 86400000 * 5) {
            return {classes: 'active'};
        }
    },
    startDate: '0'
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    selectedDay = e.date;
    selectedDay = selectedDay.getTime(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it's still happening today to bootstrap's datepicker. The reason is that the `beforeshowday` fires before the `changeDate`. So every time after you click a new day, the `beforeshowday` goes first (with the old date) then the `changeDate` happens afterwards. No matter how I look at it. I feel like this is a bug that they should fix, since the style should work with the new date. Thus the `changeDate` should go before **anything else**.

Anyway, the solution is in fact really simple. Just force a `update` in your `changeDate` after you change your date, and it will fire the `beforeShowDay` with the new date. Here is my code snippet as an example:

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        beforeShowDay:function hday(date){
            return (is_pay_day() && day_diff(date)<14 && day_diff(date)>0 ) ?  {classes: 'highlight'} : {} ;
        }
    }).datepicker('setDate', 'today').on("changeDate", function (ev) {
        //set the new date if one is selected
        (!ev.date) ? $(this).datepicker('setDate', selectedDate) : selectedDate = ev.date;
        $('#datepickerInput').val(selectedDate.toDateString());
        //force the update, so the beforeShowDay will be triggered 
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('update',selectedDate);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After think and search a lot I found a possible solution, If it's effective or not, just tell me, thanks

```
var selectedDay = new Date().getTime();
$('.datepicker').datepicker({

            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var d = date.getTime();
                if (d > selectedDay && d < selectedDay + 1 + 86400000 * 5) {
                    return {classes: 'active'};
                }
            },
            startDate: '0'

        }).on('changeDate', function(e){

            selectedDay = e.date;
            selectedDay = selectedDay.getTime();
            $(".datepicker").data("datepicker").fill();
        });
```