# Update bootstrap 3 datepicker options dynamically?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

This datepicker it is already created with other default options, but I need to update it with the following new options and it does not seem to work:

```js
// new options
var new_options = {
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'es'
}

// update values
$("#fecha_periodo").datepicker("update", new_options );
```

I would also like to update other options like `daysOfWeekDisabled`, `viewMode` and so on.

Comment: From the update area within the bootstrap datepicker, it seems very clear that the options specify updating values. https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update

Comment: I saw that already, it changes values but not options

Comment: Try the format option. https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format

Comment: looks great but I would like to update options at once, there is also some other properties that need to be updated like viewMode and language

Comment: Language is one of the properties and I believe format as well.

Comment: how can I change the viewMode?

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to find how to change a simple option LOL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145474/discussion-between-cam-and-ivan-juarez).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API to change options dinamically, all availables methods are listed [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) (you can use [`setDaysOfWeekDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdaysofweekdisabled) to set dinamically days of week disabled).

You can use [`destroy`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#destroy) method to destroy datepicker instance and build it again with the new options.

Here a live example:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker();

$('#btnChange').click(function(){
  var new_options = {
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'es'
  }
  // Save value
  var value = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDates');
  // Destroy previous datepicker
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
  // Re-int with new options
  $('#datepicker').datepicker(new_options);
  // Set previous value
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDates', value);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">

<button id="btnChange" class="btn btn-primary">Change option</button>
```

Comment: I was about to change to datepicker "v4" but it does not seem to be an official site, I do not know if you have observed that there is a lot of bootstrap "datepickers" and "datetimepickers" sites that got the people confused and do not know which one to use, I only use bootstraps built-int.
I appreciate your answer and will use that, Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately bootstrap itself does not include a datepicker, but there are a lot of independent datepickers with bootstrap theme. In my opinion, the best one is [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) by eonasdan. It uses momentjs, it has a rich API and it's well documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all about new version (Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 Docs) at https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

```
let new_options = {
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
        down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-remove'
    },
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    date: new Date()
}

if(condition1){
        new_options.daysOfWeekDisabled = [0,2,3,4,5,6];
        new_options.viewMode = 'years';
        new_options.format = 'MM/YYYY';
    }else(condition2){
        new_options.viewMode = 'years';
        new_options.format = 'YYYY';
    }
    // Destroy previous datepicker
    $('.datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").destroy();
    // Re-int with new options
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(new_options);
```

Sorry for my poor english please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a hacking solution that works for me to change the datepicker options dynamically after I initiate a bootstrap datepicker object.

```
var id = "MyDatepicker"
var beginDate = new Date();
var endDate =  new Date(2022, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);

function myCallBack(date) {
    if ((beginDate <= date) && (date <= endDate)){
        return {classes: 'activeClass'};
    }
    return;
}

$('#' + id ).datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    language: 'en'
});

$('#' + id ).datepicker('_process_options', {
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return myCallBack(date);
    }
}).datepicker('update','')
```

In this case. I apply a class to a range of dates on the datepicker.

I use the "non public" datepicker method '_process_options' to change intern datepicker methods.

With this method I can change all the options of the datepicker instance because the '_process_options' has no method validator.

Also I use the method 'update' bacause the dobbleclick bug: [bootstrap datepicker, beforeShowDay works after second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599720/bootstrap-datepicker-beforeshowday-works-after-second-click)