# Update DaysOfWeekDisabled of bootstrap datepicker in real time

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a datepicker created as shown below.

```
$(".datepicker-class").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startDate: date,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    datesDisabled: exclude_dates,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: disabledWeekDays
})
```

But I would like to use the function [`setDaysOfWeekDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdaysofweekdisabled) to update the days of week disabled in real time.

That means initially if `disabledWeekDays = [0]` all Sundays will be disabled.

But after that on clicking some button, I would like to disabled Mondays, how can I do that?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the document, you try to change config disabledWeekDays = [6] so see it disable All Sundays. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [`setDaysOfWeekDisabled`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdaysofweekdisabled) that:

> Sets the days of week that should be disabled. See [daysOfWeekDisabled](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled) for valid values.
>
> Omit daysOfWeekDisabled (or provide an otherwise falsey value) to unset the disabled days of week.

Here a live sample:

```js
var date = new Date();
var exclude_dates = ['2018-12-01', '2018-12-07'];
var disabledWeekDays = [0];
$(".datepicker-class").datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  startDate: date,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  datesDisabled: exclude_dates,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: disabledWeekDays
});

$('#btnDisableMon').click(function(){
  $('.datepicker-class').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekDisabled', [1]);
});

$('#btnDisableSun').click(function(){
  $('.datepicker-class').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekDisabled', [0]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-class">

<button id="btnDisableMon" class="btn btn-primary">Disable Mondays</button>
<button id="btnDisableSun" class="btn btn-primary">Disable Sundays</button>
```

Something similar was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265364/4131048). Please note that you have to add your logic if you want to check if already selected days has to be invalidated/blanked.

Comment: I tried that, but that won't have the options we set earlier like   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  startDate: date,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  datesDisabled: exclude_dates,    We need to call 'setDaysOfWeekDisabled', [0] along with the options we set.

Comment: @AbdunnasirKP take a look at the snippet provided in the answer, I think that all previous options are preserved. If you want to dinamically set other option then this question is a duplicate of the [linked one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265364/4131048).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no any inbuilt method to update datepicker options. You have to destroy previous datepicker and initialize with updated options.

below code would work for you

```
     var newOptions = {
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   startDate: date,
   autoclose: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   datesDisabled: exclude_dates,
   daysOfWeekDisabled: disabledWeekDays // Update this option value like [0] or [1]
  }

//Destroy datepicker
$('datepicker-class').datepicker('destroy');
// Re-initialize with new options
$('datepicker-class').datepicker(newOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

`daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]` - for disabled weekend days